# What exactly happens when you mute someone in CS:GO ?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When you mute someone in the game, you can't see what they write in chat, neither hear what they say.

There's something I'm unsure of though, can the muted player still see what you type in chat or hear what you say (provided he's on your team) ?

Comment: I'm going to say that it is a 99% chance that it is like every other game. You muted them, not the other way around, so unless they mute you as well, they will be able to see what you type and hear what you say

Comment: In this case, the 1% is the truth. As ever so often!

Comment: @TheBlastOne We have conflicting answers here, so we need compelling evidence on either side to decide

Comment: All I can tell ya is what my answer says...and I experience this every day. If you mute some mate, he cannot hear you anymore, and you cannot hear him anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well he hasn't muted you back has he? So he can get your output but you can't get his.

I tend to mute players whose mic might not be good, or who would talk too much or would talk random stuff. But then I still want to win so I would carry on talking to the mic knowing that he too can hear me so I'd give him info too.

They can hear and see, you can't.

Comment: I experience the opposite daily. If you mute a player in-game, you will neither hear nor read him, and he does not hear or read you. 100%! But I have no idea where the answer could come from if it is, as I believe, completely wrong.

Comment: Yes this answer is totally incorrect.  Mine below is totally correct...

I've tested with people I call.... friends....

Answer (score 1):

If you mute a player in-game, comm between you two is suppressed bi-directionally. You hear what other players say, but not the muted player, and he/she also cannot hear you, but all other players.

Same for text chats.

The only way to communicate with a muted player is using the commands (y, x, c menus).

Comment: Update: They changed that.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't "muting", it's " block communication".  Therefore logically neither can see anything the other posts if one has muted the other.